# declaration for a module that exports a self calling function

Tags: typescript, npm, webpack, typescript-typings

This should be simple but I can't seem to figure it out.
npm module next-tick does something like this in it's index.js:

```
module.exports = (function () {
    if (/*node*/) {
        return process.nextTick;
    }
    ...
    if (/*other env*/) {
        return function (cb) { setTimeout(callable(cb), 0); };
    }

    return null;
}());
```

There are no typings yet, so I created next-tick.d.ts and included it in my tsconfig.js.

However I can't figure out what it should contain:

This only thing I got working without compiler errors is this:

```
declare module "next-tick" {
    export default function(fn:Function)
}
```

and in the consuming file:

```
import nextTick from 'next-tick';
```

But when I bundle with webpack and run it, it says: `next_tick_1.default is not a function`. So it's trying to call `.default`.

What also works is if I use require (and add declarations for that with webpack typings)

```
var nextTick:(fn:Function)=>void = require('next-tick');
```

But I'm sure I should be able to do this with a typescript import?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
declare module "next-tick" {
    function nextTick (fn:Function)
    export = nextTick
}
```

This makes the function to be *the* export

To import

```
import nextTick = require('next-tick')
```

The ES6 import syntax cannot be used because this is just a function, not a module (as required in ES6)